# How do I create a delegate to assign to the onClick event of a dynamic menu?

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, menuitem, menustrip

I want to do the following, but I receive an error arguement type `DoWindow` is not assignable to parameter `System.EventHandler`

How do I get my delegate to inherit from `System.EventHandler`?

```
 public delegate void DoWindow(MdiLayout layoutInstruction) ;

 private ToolStripMenuItem MakeWindowMenu()
    {
        var tsi = new ToolStripMenuItem("Window");
        tsi.DropDownItems.Add(CreateMenuItem("Cascade","Cascade the features",    DoWindowLayout(MdiLayout.Cascade)));
        tsi.DropDownItems.Add(CreateMenuItem("Tile Vertical","Tile the features vertically", this.DoWindowTileVertically));

       //etc
        return tsi;
    }


private   ToolStripMenuItem CreateMenuItem(string Caption, string tooltip, EventHandler onClickEventHandler)
    {
        var item = new ToolStripMenuItem(Caption);
        item.Click += onClickEventHandler;
        item.ToolTipText = tooltip;
        return item;
    }

public DoWindow DoWindowLayout(MdiLayout layoutInstruction)
    {
        Master.MDIForm.LayoutMdi(layoutInstruction);
    }
```

Comment: Where should the parameter `layoutInstruction` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `Action` as the parameter and use an anonymous `Eventhandler` to invoke the `Action`

Something like:

```
    private ToolStripMenuItem MakeWindowMenu()
    {
        var tsi = new ToolStripMenuItem("Window");
        tsi.DropDownItems.Add(CreateMenuItem("Cascade", "Cascade the features", () => Master.MDIForm.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade)));
        tsi.DropDownItems.Add(CreateMenuItem("Tile Vertical", "Tile the features vertically", () => {  }));
        return tsi;
    }

    private ToolStripMenuItem CreateMenuItem(string Caption, string tooltip, Action onClickEventHandler)
    {
        var item = new ToolStripMenuItem(Caption);
        item.Click += (s, e) => { onClickEventHandler.Invoke(); };
        item.ToolTipText = tooltip;
        return item;
    }
```

Comment: i like the idea, but when i try it I get an error "incompatible anonymous function signature"

Comment: I am using the same and everything compiled fine, I also tested and it worked. Strange...

Comment: I have updated my answer, it removes the Delegate as it not longer needed, see if that compiles on your end.

Comment: thank you, It works correctly now, and it also may have worked correctly the first time - since I was editing my code rather than doing a complete copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

Your custom EventHandlers need to contain the required signature of the methods. In other words:
ToolStripMenuItemClick requires a method with the signature

```
delegate void EventHandler(object Sender, EventArgs e);
```

so you'll need to alter the signature of your delegate and the corresponding method.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.click.aspx) for further reference.

Comment: If I alter the signature of the delegate to match, how do I pass the layoutInstruction parameter?